# Using node.js modules with atom-shell

Tags: javascript, electron

I started to have a look at the atom-shell and as documented there is a possibility to access native node modules: https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules.md

So is there any possibility to use those node modules from the javascript code which is executed inside the atom shell, for example to execute sql statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, of course, that's the point :)  Once built correctly, you require native node.js modules just like you require JavaScript-based ones.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having the same question, the remote-object can handle this:

https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/remote.md